# Why does Laravel Voyager setting() display a different URL on the front end?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I'm using Laravel Voyager admin panel and I have created a value in the admin that is retrieved via `{{ setting('site.logo') }}`.

On the admin panel, which I did not write the core code, the path returned is `storage/settings/monthyear/image.png` but when called on the front end it's missing `storage` in the page `settings/monthyear/image.png`.

I don't understand why. I would expect them to both be the same path.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this:

`{{ Voyager::image( setting('site.logo') ); }}`

You can find it in their [docs](https://voyager.devdojo.com/academy/settings/) 3:05 of video