# Why images doesn't display Laravel Voyager?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I have problem, recently i moved to ubuntu from windows and I had none issues so
i was shocked that application doesn't show images in admin panel and in front-side

So what i have:

Admin panel: [admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrH2O.png)

Front-side : [front-side 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fQHt.png), [front-side 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7KyH.png)

I use{{ asset('storage/' . setting('site.logo')) }}

I changed App_Url to http://127.0.0.1:8000

I've tried to update pictures but nothing and I've tried to change {{ asset('storage/' . setting('site.logo')) }} to storage/{{setting('site.logo')}}

What should i do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76064822/2549284) from the similar question.